# Avoiding overflow working modulo p

Tags: c++, c, integer-overflow

As part of a university assignment, I have to implement in C scalar multiplication on an elliptic curve modulo p = 2^255 - 19. Since all computations are made modulo p, it seems enough to work with the primitive type (unsigned long).

However, if a and b are two integers modulo p, there is a risk of overflow computing a*b. I am not sure how to avoid that. Is the following code correct ?

```
long a = ...;
long b = ...;
long c = (a * b) % p;
```

Or should I rather cast a and b first ?

```
long a = ...;
long b = ...;
long long a1 = (long long) a;
long long b1 = (long long) b;
long c = (long) ((a1 * b1) % p);
```

I was also thinking or working with long long all along.

Comment: use this relationship: `(a * b) % m == (a%m * b%m) % m`

Comment: There is actually no guarantee that `long long` is larger than `long` - the standard only dictates minimum sizes of those types

Comment: p is 2^255 - 19, so I think that taking the modulo before the multiplication is not enough

Comment: Your `p` has 255 binary digits so all the native types are too narrow.

Comment: @Raf yup - you are going to need to use/write a multi-precision library.  Still that relationship will keep your numbers to max 512 bits long.

Comment: @molbdnilo I thought that long was 32 bytes minimum, it makes 256 bits, doesn't it ?

Comment: @Raf fundamental types: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types  `long` is min 32 __bits__

Comment: @Raf They're usually 32 *bits* (four eight-bit bytes), unless you have access to some seriously exotic hardware.

Comment: @Raf the standard(s) dictate the size of types in *bits* because a byte does not even have to be 8 bits.

Comment: Ok I misread the documentation, thanks ! However, I think my question is valid in the case where `p` is just smaller than the type limit

Comment: @Raf.: My answer revolves on what you said in last comment. If it is wthin limits how things would work.

Comment: If you have 2 numbers that say fit into 32 bits each and you multiply them together you will needs at most 64 bits for the result (double the original size).  You can the use the modulus relationship above to stop the uncontrolled growth of the numbers.  Re you question: 2^255 - 19 fits in 256 bits so you need to do multi-precision maths with a type supporting 512 bits. There are libraries to do this or you can write one using an array to hold your number.

Comment: @Raf Why is this tagged *C++*?

Comment: @raf [Modular exponentiation without range restriction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187257/modular-exponentiation-without-range-restriction) may be of value if the native types are sufficient.  Although I doubt  even `uintmax_t` will be 256 bits on your platform.  Look to its `powmodmax_high()` to see how you might code your own extend math solution.

Comment: Errr you need to learn arithmetic (mod p) [2^255 - 19] (mod n) is actually quite easy to do.  You can use Primitive root modulo n to reduce the problem.

Comment: @Biffen I use C++ for the program that led me to ask this. From your question, I understand that I should use it only for specific C++ functionalities, tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Raf C and C++ are two different languages. Which one is this question about?

Answer (score 1):

I recently came to this same problem.

First of all I'm going to assume you mean 32-*bit* integers (after reading your comments), but I think this applies to Big Integers as well (because doing a naive multiplication means doubling the word size and is going to be slow as well).

**Option 1**

We use the following property:

**Proposition.** `a*b mod m = (a - m)*(b - m) mod m`
**Proof.**

```
(a - m)*(b - m) mod m =  
(a*b - (a+b)*m + m^2) mod m =  
(a*b mod m - ((a+b) + m)*m mod m) mod m =  
(a*b mod m) mod m = a*b mod m
```

q.e.d.

Moreover, if a,b approx m, then `(a - m)*(b - m) mod m = (a - m)*(b - m)`. You will need to address the case for when a,b > m, however I think the validity of `(m - a)*(m - b) mod m = a*b mod m` is a corollary of the above Proposition; and of course don't do this when the difference is very big (small modulus, big a or b; or vice versa) or it will overflow.

**Option 2**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

```
uint64_t mul_mod(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t m)
{
   uint64_t d = 0, mp2 = m >> 1;
   int i;
   if (a >= m) a %= m;
   if (b >= m) b %= m;
   for (i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
   {
       d = (d > mp2) ? (d << 1) - m : d << 1;
       if (a & 0x8000000000000000ULL)
           d += b;
       if (d >= m) d -= m;
       a <<= 1;
   }
   return d;
}
```

And also, assuming `long double` and 32 or 64 bit integers (not arbitrary precision) you can exploit the machine priority on most significant bits of different types:

> On computer architectures where an extended precision format with at least 64 bits of mantissa is available (such as the long double type of most x86 C compilers), the following routine is faster than any algorithmic solution, by employing the trick that, by hardware, floating-point multiplication results in the most significant bits of the product kept, while integer multiplication results in the least significant bits kept

And do:

```
uint64_t mul_mod(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t m)
{
   long double x;
   uint64_t c;
   int64_t r;
   if (a >= m) a %= m;
   if (b >= m) b %= m;
   x = a;
   c = x * b / m;
   r = (int64_t)(a * b - c * m) % (int64_t)m;
   return r < 0 ? r + m : r;
}
```

These are guaranteed to not overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The whole operation(multiplication) is being done keeping in mind the type of the operands. You multiplied two `long` variables and the result if greater than what `long` variable can hold, it will overflow.

`((a%p)*(b%p))%p` this gives one protection that it wraps around `p` but what is being said in earlier case would still hold - `(a%p)*(b%p)` still can overflow. (considering that `a`,`b` is of type `long`).

If you store the values of `long` in `long long` no need to cast. But yes the result will now overflow when the multiplication yields the value greater than what `long long` can hold.

To give you a clarification:-

```
long a,b;
..
long long p = (a*b)%m;
```

This won't help. The multiplication when done is `long` arithmetic. Doesn't matter where we store the end result. It depends on the type of the operands.

Now look at this

`long c = (long) ((a1 * b1) % p);` here the result will be two `long long`  multiplication and will overflow based on max value `long long` can hold but still there is a chance of overflow when you assign it to `long`.

If `p` is `255` byte you can't realize what you want using built in types `long` or `long long` types using `32` or `64` bit system. Down the line when we have `512` bit system this would surely be possible. Also one thing to note is when `p=2`<sup>255</sup>`-19` then there is hardly any practicality involved in doing modular arithmetic with it.

If `sizeof long` is equal to `sizeof long long` as in ILP64 and LP64 then using `long` and `long long` would give you no result as such. But if `sizeof long long` is greater than `sizeof long` it is useful in saving the operands in `long long` to prevent overflow of the multiplication.

Also another way around is to write your own big integer library(multiple precision integer library) or use one which is already there(maybe like [this](https://gmplib.org/)). The idea revolves around the fact that the larger types are realized using something as simple as `char` and then doing operation on it. This is an implementation issue and there are many implementation around this same theme.

Comment: @coderredoc That was an attempt to thank you for your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

With a 255+ bit integer requirement, standard operations and the C library are insufficient.

Follows in the general algorithm to  write your own modular multiplication.

```
myint mod(myint a, myint m);
myint add(myint a, myint b);  // this may overflow
int   cmp(myint a, myint b);
int   isodd(myint a);
myint halve(myint a);

// (a+b)%mod
myint addmodmax(myint a, myint b, myint m) {
  myint sum = add(a,b);
  if (cmp(sum,a) < 0) {
    sum = add(mod(add(sum, 1),m), mod(myint_MAX,m)); // These additions do not overflow
  }
  return mod(sum, m);
}

// (a*b)%mod
myint mulmodmax(myint a, myint b, myint m) {
  myint prod = 0;
  while (cmp(b,0) > 0) {
    if (isodd(b)) {
      prod = addmodmax(prod, a, m);
    }
    b = halve(b);
    a = addmodmax(a, a, m);
  }
  return prod;
}
```